# selenium python - Extraer datos de una lista desplegada por un boton

Tags: python, selenium, botón

estoy haciendo web-scraping de una pagina. Quiero extraer las marcas de autos a partir del filtro de marcas que se tiene, al inspeccionar el html me doy cuenta que este filtro no está con el tag de un botón, además cuando se le hace click de forma manual, la estructura del html cambia agregando nuevas lineas de codigo.
He tratado lo siguiente:

```
driver.get(url_base)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'body > div.layout > div > div > div.filters-canvas > div.filter-position > div:nth-child(3)'))).click()

sleep(10)

#Buscar un objeto antes del boton
aaaaaa = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'body > div.layout > div > div > div.filters-canvas > div.filter-position > div:nth-child(1)')
print(aaaaaa.get_attribute('outerHTML'))

#Buscar un obejeto en las nuevas lineas de codigo aparecidas por el boton
sss = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'body > div.layout > div > div > div.filters-canvas > div.filter-position > div.filter.selected-filter > div > div > div > div.select-canvas > div > ul > li:nth-child(5) > span')
print(sss.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
```

Puede encontrar un objeto si esta pertenece a la pagina antes de hacer click, pero para el segundo caso, no encuentra el path hacia los nuevas lineas generadas por el boton, sospecho que realmente no está haciendo click al boton